# Why delphi not recognizing an object?

Tags: delphi

Since EditTexto is an object of form1 (which I'm working on), why is it not recognized when I try:

```
Texto:= EditTexto.Text;
```

????

if I use Form1.EditTexto.Text it seems to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The text code was not into the scope of an object of the form. It was just into the unit. I believe that was the problem. After I move the text to the "onclick" event of a button it started recognizing the editTexto object. Does that makes sense?

Before:

```
    unit Banri;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Clipbrd;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    EditTexto: TEdit;
    ButtonGO: TButton;
    procedure ButtonGOClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  SL: TStringList;
  Count: Integer;
  Appwin : hWnd;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

  var
  TextoCompleto: String;


begin
  TextoCompleto:= EditTexto.Text;
  Appwin:= FindWindow(PChar(0),'Banrisul');
  if Appwin <> 0 then
  begin
      StringReplace(TextoCompleto, '.', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

      SL:= TStringList.Create;
      try
        ExtractStrings([' '], [], PChar(TextoCompleto), SL);
        WriteLn(SL.Text);
        ReadLn;
      finally
        SL.Free;
  end;
      Count:= 0;
      while Count <> SL.Count - 1 do
        begin
          Clipboard.AsText:= SL[Count];; //place text in clipboard
          //if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
          //do something with text
          ShowMessage(Clipboard.AsText);
          Clipboard.AsText:= SL[Count + 1];; //place next line text in clipboard
          //if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
          //do something with text
          inc(Count);
        end; //while Count <> SL.Count - 1 do
      SL.Free;
  end; //if Appwin <> 0 then

end.
```

After:

```
unit Banri;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Clipbrd;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    EditTexto: TEdit;
    ButtonGO: TButton;
    procedure ButtonGOClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  SL: TStringList;
  Count: Integer;
  Appwin : hWnd;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

  var
  TextoCompleto: String;


procedure TForm1.ButtonGOClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TextoCompleto:= EditTexto.Text;
  Appwin:= FindWindow(PChar(0),'Banrisul');
  if Appwin <> 0 then
  begin
      StringReplace(TextoCompleto, '.', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

      SL:= TStringList.Create;
      try
        ExtractStrings([' '], [], PChar(TextoCompleto), SL);
        WriteLn(SL.Text);
        ReadLn;
      finally
        SL.Free;
  end;
      Count:= 0;
      while Count <> SL.Count - 1 do
        begin
          Clipboard.AsText:= SL[Count];; //place text in clipboard
          //if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
          //do something with text
          ShowMessage(Clipboard.AsText);
          Clipboard.AsText:= SL[Count + 1];; //place next line text in clipboard
          //if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
          //do something with text
          inc(Count);
        end; //while Count <> SL.Count - 1 do
      SL.Free;
  end; //if Appwin <> 0 then
end;

end.
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that you asked. This "answer" relies on lots of details that we did not have. Your fundamental problem is that you are not spending time over your questions.

Comment: As harsh as it may appear, this question (and answer) really should be deleted, because it is directly related to the other question of yours. It may take some time to get used to how StackOverflow works, since it's not any regular Forums site, but once you get the hang of it there's some great resources here for you. But you're just expected to take your own time and only use our time when you really get super stuck. Always reproduce issues before seeking help.